# Dynamic atoms in Clojure

Tags: dynamic, clojure, binding

I am new to Clojure and a bit confused about dynamic atoms. I think I understand use-cases for dynamic binding as well as atoms. But often I see definitions like this

```
(def ^:dynamic *variable* (atom nil))
```

What would be the purpose of a dynamic atom?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A dynamic variable is for sharing state within a thread. An atom is for a variable that might change. Thus, a dynamic variable containing an atom is useful for state that is scoped per-thread and might change. For example, it is convenient to use for per-request data in an HTTP handler. Of course, you can just use a dynamic variable and `set!` it a bunch, since you don't need to coordinate across threads. But we have better functions for manipulating atoms than for vars, so people often do this.

Comment: I'm also a newbie, working with Clojure 1.10, and it seems `set!` on a dynamic *global* var (*outside* a thread or `binding` scope) is problematic. Quote from [https://clojure.org/reference/vars#set](https://clojure.org/reference/vars#set): "Currently, it is an error to attempt to set the root binding of a var using set!, i.e. var assignments are thread-local." **What I don't understand** is if using an `atom` in any case, why is it still marked `^:dynamic` ?

Comment: @fr13d You would establish an initial per-thread value with `binding`, not with `set!`, and then mutate it further on that thread with `swap!`.